How to stop pipewriter write into pipeline while pipereader thrown an exception?

I am trying to read data from a large file and process it by System.IO.PipeLines, then if an exception is thrown on the pipereader and how can i stop the pipewriter correctly?
PipeReader has a method called CompleteAsync (Exception? exception = default), should i pass the exception into the method?
If there is still some data remaining in the pipeline, but both PipeReader and PipeWriter are completed, will GC collect this remaining garbage?

Codes:
private static async Task FillPipeAsync(string path, PipeWriter writer)
{
    const int minimumBufferSize = 4096;
    using var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

    while (true)
    {
        var memory = writer.GetMemory(minimumBufferSize);
        int bytesRead = await fs.ReadAsync(memory);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        writer.Advance(bytesRead);
        FlushResult result = await writer.FlushAsync();
        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    await writer.CompleteAsync();
}

private static async Task ReadPipeAsync(PipeReader reader)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var result = await reader.ReadAsync();
        var buffer = result.Buffer;

        while (TryReadMessage(ref buffer, out var message))
        {
            // may throw exception
            Handle(message);
        }

        reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    await reader.CompleteAsync();
}


"while pipereader thrown an exception" sounds like it takes minutes to throw an exception.

@ThomasWeller lol, not exactly. Do u have any suggestion about the question?
